# Using Money-Rails Gem for Multiple Currencies [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, currency, money-rails

I have a Rails 4 app using the [money-rails gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) to define money objects. I have a money object called `default_price_cents` and a `currency` column on the User model to define currencies for each individual user (as seen [here](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#instance-currencies)):

```
class AddDefaultsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_money :users, :default_price
    add_column :users, :currency, :string
  end
end
```

My **user.rb** has the following lines:

```
register_currency :usd

monetize :default_price_cents, with_model_currency: :default_price_currency
```

Users then define their currency in **registration** (HAML):

```
.form-group
  = f.label :currency
  = f.select :default_price_currency, [['USD','usd'],['CAD','cad'],['DKK','dkk']]
```

I have tried to have this set with both `:default_price_currency` as well as `:currency`.

In my **view**, I have:

```
humanized_money_with_symbol @default_price
```

**The Problem:**

When this I display the default price in my view, it for some reason uses the currency I have defined with `register_currency` in my *model*, instead of using the currency defined by the user upon registration. **How do I get the app to refer to the user defined currency instead of the registered currency for that model?**

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!

Well, embarrassingly, writing this post helped me to find the answer only a few seconds later. I'll leave it up for anyone who may need it.

I've changed this line in **user.rb**:

```
monetize :default_price_cents, with_model_currency: :default_price_currency
```

to look like

```
monetize :default_price_cents, with_model_currency: :currency
```

as well as changed the `default_price_currency` to `currency` in my views.